# Where can I download Ubuntu Server 12.04 or 14.04?

Tags: system-installation

Where can I download Ubuntu Server 12.04 or 14.04?

Comment: https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads

Comment: 14.04 is still supported, until 2019. 12.04 is not, unless you have a payed support and you don't otherwise you wouldn't be asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can download them from ubuntu old releases page:

http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/